# How do I get a Powershell process that was opened by another Powershell process?

Tags: powershell

I am running multiple PowerShell scripts at once. I would like to be able to wait on certain ones to finish before opening new scripts. Basically, I was thinking if I could find the command line option that ran it something like "`powershell.exe -Path "<script dir>`" that would do it.

I tried doing a `Get-Process | gm` to find any parameters that I could call to get that information and I didn't see any (doesn't mean they aren't there) I tried looking through Task Manager to see if I could view something through the gui that I could link to but that didn't help either.

I hope I can get something like

```
Start-Process -FilePath ".\<script>.ps1" -ArgumentList "<args>"
do
{
    sleep 10
}
until ((Get-Process -ProcessName "PowerShell" | where "<paramater>" -EQ ".\<script>")
```

I need to wait until that process is done but I don't want to put a wait at the end of the Start-Process because after that Start-Process kicks off I need some other items to go to while my .\ is running. I just need it to wait before another section of script kicks off.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something that would be better achieved by PowerShell's built-in support for [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) -- waiting for those is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the "Job" cmdlets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-6

And the $PID automatic variable, this will give the process ID of the current PowerShell session.

Comment: Thank you, just needed that refresher. I completely forgot about the job commands. That's what I need.

Comment: Last question, do you know if scope changes inside a job?